# User input for custom .format()

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I got a list of tuples with 4 variables, those will be printed in a single line each and I want the user to specify the format of those prints.

**This is my code so far:**

```
mylist = [
    ("Monday", "13", "November", "2017"),
    ("Tuesday", "14", "November", "2017"),
    ("Wednesday", "15", "November", "2017")]
# Note: The real list have a thousand of items, not just 3.

custom_format = self.GUI_field_where_user_types.get_text()
for item in mylist:
    weekday = item[0]
    daynumber = item[1]
    month = item[2]
    year = item[3]
    print(eval(custom_format))

# Example custom_format: '"{0}, {1} of {2} from year {3}".format(weekday, daynumber, month, year)'
```

For tests, I just tried with the input above and it obviously works, but I don't want to use eval as it's obviously too dangerous. So my question is: How can I make the user define the format in a safe way?

**Note:** The user should be able to only edit the string before the .format() method `"{0}, {1} of {2} from year {3}"`, blocking access to any python command, but allowing him to use only the variables that he want, not always the 4 of them. Some examples might be:

- {0}, {1} of {2}
- {3}, {1} at month {2}
- {0}, {1} of {2} from year {3}
- {1} whatever {2} -- {3}

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. What is it you type in as input? This: `"{0}, {1} of {2} from year {3}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straightforward.  Just call `.format` on the input string, and pass the items as parameters using the parameter unpacking syntax:

```
mylist = [
    ("Monday", "13", "November", "2017"),
    ("Tuesday", "14", "November", "2017"),
    ("Wednesday", "15", "November", "2017")]

fmt = input('Format? ')
for item in mylist:
    print(fmt.format(*item))
```

Execution:

```
Format? {0}, {1} of {2}
Monday, 13 of November
Tuesday, 14 of November
Wednesday, 15 of November
```

To handle the user entering an invalid format, you can catch the exception and try again:

```
while True:
    try:
        fmt = input('Format? ')
        for item in mylist:
            print(fmt.format(*item))
        break
    except (IndexError,ValueError,KeyError):
        print('Invalid format.')
```

Execution:

```
Format? {A}
Invalid format.
Format? {4}
Invalid format.
Format? {
Invalid format.
Format? The year is {3}
The year is 2017
The year is 2017
The year is 2017
```

Comment: This is a nice solution for the specific problem but not using `datetime` when handling time is a big mistake (my opinion).

Comment: @Anton Just because the OP has dates as an example doesn't mean the variables will always be dates.  This is a generic solution.

Comment: @Anton In addition, why format the strings through a `datetime` object when they are already formatted correctly?  Use `datetime` when you don't know that "11/13" is a Monday in November.

Comment: Both are valid points. I however think datetime is a fail-safe library to handle dates. He/she could get timedeltas, add timedeltas, group them and what not. Not to mention all ways to output the dates.

Comment: The dates were indeed just an example. I was interested in how to handle custom format to apply that in strings. Mainly because I need the output on spanish, so "November" scrapped from datetime wouldn't do it, should be "Noviembre". I first get the dates and then translate them using a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method to arrange format:

```
def fill_format(custom_format, date):
    used_vars = []
    used_indexes = []

    #Look for what is used
    for i in range(len(date)):
        if "{"+str(i)+"}" in custom_format:
            used_vars.append(date[i])
            used_indexes.append(i)

    #Replace indexes starting from 0
    for new_index, used_index in enumerate(used_indexes):
        custom_format = custom_format.replace("{"+str(used_index)+"}", "{"+str(new_index)+"}")

    return custom_format.format(*used_vars)

mylist = [
    ("Monday", "13", "November", "2017"),
    ("Tuesday", "14", "November", "2017"),
    ("Wednesday", "15", "November", "2017")]

custom_format = "{3}, {1} at month {2}"
for item in mylist:
    print(fill_format(custom_format, item))
```

Output:

```
2017, 13 at month November
2017, 14 at month November
2017, 15 at month November
```

**EDIT:**

If a date has always 4 time units, you can use:

```
def fill_format(custom_format, date):
    return custom_format.replace("{0}", date[0]).replace("{1}", date[1]).replace("{2}", date[2]).replace("{3}", date[3])
```

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing asking this. The key part is that user input provides an unknown amount of {0}, so I can't have a hardcoded `.format(1,2,3)` since I don't even know if there will be 3 items or 500. Test my own response, as it works. I still think there should be a better way. Edit: Screenshot http://prntscr.com/h95x7b notice that user can type the Formato.

Comment: @Saelyth I changed the function. I claim that it can handle even you change item length from 4 to 5 or to another number. Assumed your `custom_format` is just a string including some of `{0}`,`{1}`, `{2}`, ... Tell me if I'm wrong or the code doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it works. However I will accept Mark answer as it removes a lot of code and keeps it simple with the same result. Hope you understand.

Comment: I would accept his answer too. I was trying to use `{3}, {1} at month {2}` as the format because it doesn't start from `0`. But I didn't know my functions last row(`return custom_format.format(*used_vars)`) handles that. I've learned too. I gave +1 to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Stick with the standardised [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html)format. With datetime we can use the powerful strftime to print a datetime according to a set of predefined patterns. Consider this example:

```
import datetime

mylist = [
    ("Monday", "13", "November", "2017"),
    ("Tuesday", "14", "November", "2017"),
    ("Wednesday", "15", "November", "2017")]

custom_format = "%A, %d of %B from year %Y"

for item in mylist:
    # Create datetime object
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join([*item]),"%A-%d-%B-%Y")
    # Print with format
    print(dt.strftime(custom_format))
```

Prints:

```
Monday, 13 of November from year 2017
Tuesday, 14 of November from year 2017
Wednesday, 15 of November from year 2017
```

---

And if you'd like to create your "own language" use a dictionary to map to the standard ones. Consider this example:

```
import datetime
import re

mylist = [
    ("Monday", "13", "November", "2017"),
    ("Tuesday", "14", "November", "2017"),
    ("Wednesday", "15", "November", "2017")]

d = {"WEEKDAY": "%A",
     "DAYNUMBER": "%d",
     "MONTH": "%B",
     "YEAR": "%Y"}

input_ = "YEAR-%m-DAYNUMBER is equal to WEEKDAY, DAYNUMBER of MONTH from year YEAR"

# Use re library to change WEEKDAY --> %A and so on...
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')
custom_format = pattern.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], input_)

for item in mylist:
    # Create datetime object
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('-'.join([*item]),"%A-%d-%B-%Y")
    # Print with format
    print(dt.strftime(custom_format))
```

Outputs:

```
2017-11-13 is equal to Monday, 13 of November from year 2017
2017-11-14 is equal to Tuesday, 14 of November from year 2017
2017-11-15 is equal to Wednesday, 15 of November from year 2017
```

This gives all the flexibility you need with minimal code.